# how to make beforeInsert trigger to set specific value in column if other column is null

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

i have this table , that  i want to make before insert trigger

that will check if the new inserted value had null in column A , then it will insert 0 in column B + it will set created_On with sysdate

This is my desired output

```
COLUMN_A COLUMN_B CREATED_BY UPDATE_BY
  null     0       sysdate   sysdate
  12       1       sysdate   sysdate
```

And this my trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SCH.TABLEA_TRG BEFORE 
 INSERT or update
 ON SCH.TABLEA REFERENCING OLD AS old NEW AS new
FOR EACH ROW
begin
if inserting then
:NEW.CREATED_ON := sysdate ;
:NEW.UPDATED_ON := sysdate ;
if :COLUMN_A  is null
 then set :new.COLUMN_B 0
else  :COLUMN_A  is not null
then set :new.COLUMN_B 1 
elsif updating then
:NEW.UPDATED_ON := sysdate ;
end if;

end;
```

but it has syntax error and can't figure it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were several mistakes - missing :NEW before some bind variables, missing end if, there is no "set" command, incorrect column name.  This seemed to compile.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tablea_trg BEFORE
    INSERT OR UPDATE ON tablea
    REFERENCING
            OLD AS old
            NEW AS new
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF inserting THEN
        :new.created_on := SYSDATE;
        :new.updated_on := SYSDATE;
        IF :new.column_a IS NULL THEN
            :new.column_b := 0;
        ELSE
            IF :new.column_a IS NOT NULL THEN
                :new.column_b := 1;
            END IF;
        END IF;

    ELSIF updating THEN
        :new.updated_on := SYSDATE;
    END IF;
END;
```

However dull it is, the [Oracle Help](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#LNPLS20041) is always a good reference.

Comment: The "ELSE IF :new.column_a IS NOT NULL THEN" is useless...

IF :new.column_a IS NULL THEN :new.column_b := 0;
ELSE :new.column_b := 1;
END IF;

Comment: @BartmanDilaw - was just trying to get it to compile. OP can determine the logic he/she needs.